# Non-inverting op-amp amplifier gain as open-loop gain goes to infinity (limit calculation)

Tags: operational-amplifier

Why is the following true?

[image]

I can't seem to understand why. Shouldn't it just be infinity/1+infinity which is approximately 1?

It's comparing the v<sub>o</sub>/v<sub>in</sub> of a non-inverting amplifier with finite gain with that of one with infinite gain.

Comment: infinity/(1+infinity) is an *indeterminate form*, it isn't equal to 1. If you get an indeterminate form it means you haven't found a solution and you need to try some other approach.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just follow the following approach:

$$\begin{align*}
&= \lim_{A\rightarrow\infty}\frac{A}{1+A\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_F}}\\\\
&= \lim_{A\rightarrow\infty}\frac{A}{1+A\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_F}}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{A}}{\frac{1}{A}}\\\\
&= \lim_{A\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{A}+\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_F}}\\\\
&= \frac{1}{\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_F}}\\\\
&= \frac{R_1+R_F}{R_1}\\\\
&= 1+\frac{R_F}{R_1}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

This is of infinity/infinity form. So we will do a work around to calculate this limit.
$$\frac{A}{1+\frac {AR_i}{R_i+R_f}} = \frac{A}{A(\frac{1}{A}+\frac {R_i}{R_i+R_f})} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{A}+\frac {R_i}{R_i+R_f}}   $$

Now you can apply limits.

$$\lim_{A\to \infty}  \frac{1}{\frac{1}{A}+\frac {R_i}{R_i+R_f}} =  \frac{1}{0+\frac {R_i}{R_i+R_f}} =\frac {R_i+R_f}{R_i} $$

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I think this is the same approach as jonk's.

Answer (score 5):

We can write your equation in a slightly different way 
$$A_{CL} = \frac{A}{1 + Aβ}$$

Where \$β = \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_F}\$

And now if we divide this by \$A\$ we are going to get this:

$$A_{CL} = \frac{1}{(1/A) + β}$$

So, now \$A\$ is approaching the infinity \$(1/A = 0)\$

we can see that the closed loop gain is equal to:

\$\Large \frac{1}{\beta} =\frac{R_1+ R_F}{R_1} =\frac{R_1}{R_1}+\frac{R_F}{R_1}=  1 +\frac{R_F}{R_1}\$

Answer (score 5):

A less rigorous method is to look at the denominator, and notice that, as A gets very large, A(R1/(R1 + RF)) gets much larger than 1, so the 1 can be discarded.

Then the ratio is easily evaluated and the A's drop out.

Answer (score 5):

\$\infty/\infty\$ is an indeterminate form, so use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

$$\lim_{A\rightarrow\infty}\frac{A}{1+A\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_F}} = \frac{\frac{d}{dA}(A)}{\frac{d}{dA}(1+A\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_F})} = \frac{1}{\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_F}} = 1 + \frac{R_F}{R_1}$$